# Rails 4.2.4 Metal API Undefined Method `to_i'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I've been upgrading my rails application from 3.2.8 to 4.2.4 and I have about 98% of the application working, but I have run into a major roadblock with the API. I continue to get a strange error that I am unable to find a solution for.

If all of the code in KnowledgeChecks > Status is commented out, I don't get an error, but If I have the slightest amount of code in there I get an undefined method. Also, if I run the same code in the Console (outside of the API controller) I don't get any errors.

This is what I currently have:

API Application controller:

```
class Api::ApplicationController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::RespondWith
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionController::Head
  # include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods

  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views"

  respond_to :js

  skip_before_filter :set_guard
  before_filter      :require_api_conversation_token!

  def require_api_conversation_token!
    @user = User.where(:api_token => params[:api_token]).first
    head :unauthorized unless @user
  end

end
```

The Problem Controller (Create works, Status fails)

```
class Api::KnowledgeChecksController < Api::ApplicationController

  def create
    @objective = Objective.find_by_id params[:id]
    if @objective && @user.courses.include?(@objective.course)
      KnowledgeCheck.create!(
        :objective_id => @objective.id,
        :user_id      => @user.id,
        :status       => "in progress"
      )
      head :ok
    else
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def status
    kchk = @user.knowledge_checks.where(:objective_id => params[:id])

    if kchk.length > 0 && params[:status] && params[:score]
      kchk.last.status = params[:status]
      kchk.last.score  = params[:score]
      kchk.last.save
      head :ok
    else
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

end
```

Results in the log:

```
Started POST "/api/knowledge_checks/status/?api_token=TOKEN&id=ID&status=STATUS&score=SCORE"

Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    /Users/ehay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was really really dumb. In hindsight, I'm not sure why the code was working in Rails 3.2.

Basically, "status" is a helper method for ActionController::Metal. If I added anything to the status call, rails thought I was trying to use it with the helper. Changing the name of the method in the controller fixed my problems.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html